# Easiest and fastest way to remove files based on name from keras batch dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I'm fairly new to Keras and I'm having a bit of an issue I'm trying to remove image files with a certain name from my validation set so that I can create a new batch dataset without them.  Removing them manually isn't an option as I'm trying to achieve the same split I had when creating the validation set originally with them in the dataset.  I'm using `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` to create the validation set, any help is appreciated.

PS: sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar to @jahantaila's answer. Although, I do not think it's a good thing to use the `os` lib here. I give an answer with the `Path` class from the `pathlib` standard library.

To perform file processing on Python there is the standard library [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this. This is the preferred way to go when you want to browse / edit files on your system in Python. You can use the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) lib or the module [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) if you want to do very specific manipulations, which does not seem to be your case.

In your case you seem to want to delete some files matching some conditions. Here is an example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def keep_file(file: Path) -> bool:
  # Take decision to keep the file or not
  ... 

# Agnostic OS path with the Path object
folder = Path("path", "to", "folder")

for file in folder.iterdir():
  if not keep_file(file):
    file.unlink()
```

I invite you to read the section of [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#methods-and-properties) about Path properties to know how to access information of the file such as `name`, `suffix` etc.. You'll need them in order to fill your `keep_file` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `os` module to remove files based on their name. Here's an example code snippet that removes all files with the name `"example.jpg"` from a directory:

```
import os

directory = "path/to/validation_set"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename == "example.jpg":
        os.remove(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```

You can modify this code to remove files with a different name by changing the `"example.jpg"` string to the desired file name. Place this code before you create the `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` to remove the desired files from the directory.

```
import os

directory = "path/to/validation_set"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename == "name_to_remove.jpg":
        os.remove(os.path.join(directory, filename))

validation_set = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    ...
)
```

Note that this will permanently delete the files, so make sure you have a backup if you need to keep them.

Hope this helps!